# What is this tall flowering plant?

Tags: identification

This plant is tall, has web-shaped leaves and has a large yellow flower. It grows in Charlotte, NC, US. It takes about a week for the flowers to develop from bud to full flowering.
This plant is a perennial as it has survived for 2 years.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The pictures imply a height of considerably more than 6 inches...are you meaning the flower is 6 inches across?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right. That's a Hollyhock. Describing it as 6" tall was confusing.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcea